# Why there is no NSOperationWithBlock

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

We can have `[NSOperationQueue new] addOperationWithBlock` yet we do not have `NSOperation withBlock`?

I thought the way addOperationWithBlock is to create NSOperation first with that block and then add that to the queue. So we have a function that will do the whole thing but not the one that can do it one thing at a time?

Strange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for [`+[NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSBlockOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008157-CH1-SW4)?

Comment: Yes :) Thanks. Don't know what the downvote. I think it's a very important question.